# Android SQLiteMisuseException when calling database.rawQuery

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

I use a SQLite database in an Android application and sometimes get an SQLiteMisuseException when calling database.rawQuery(String sql, String[] selectionArgs).
This is pretty odd because this Exception appears ramdomly and I realy don't know why.

There is more informations about the Exception:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteMisuseException: library routine called out of sequence: , while compiling: SELECT PromoGuid, PromoViewCount FROM TablePromoView
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1356)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1324)
at com.my.application....
```

Does somebody had this error? Can you help me to solve it?

Thanks in advance,

PS: Sorry for my poor english, I'm from Belgium

Comment: Can you provide the code which is causing the issue?

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

[check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820556/sqlite-exception-on-resuming-android-activity). Make sure to close any open db connection/cursors before you starting another activity, etc.