# SQLiteMisuseException: error code 21 when inserting a row

Tags: android, sqlite

I sometimes get SQLiteMisuseException when row is being inserted. Application works perfectly on hundreds of devices but on one with android 3.1 there is an SQLite exception.
Stack trace:

```
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteMisuseException: error code 21: not an error
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeInsert(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:112)
```

This is a code which invoking executeInsert():

```
    final SQLiteStatement insUrlStmt = db.compileStatement("insert into urls (url,idx) values (?,?)");
    insUrlStmt.bindString(1, url)
    insUrlStmt.bindLong(2, idx);
    return insUrlStmt.executeInsert();
```

Declaration of db field:

```
    private final SQLiteDatabase db;
```

Initialization of db field (this is invoked once in onCreate() of Application class object) and reference to DataHelper is stored statically in application instance:

```
    public DataHelper(Context context) {db = new OpenHelper(context).getWritableDatabase();   }
```

OpenHelper constructor:

```
    protected OpenHelper(Context context) 
{
     super(context, "database.db", null, 1);       
}
```

I've already read this question: [Android SQLite error code 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285456/android-sqlite-error-code-21) and searched for things mentioned there.

SQLiteDatabase (db field) is opened only once and it is never closed directly from application code. Multi-thread access should not be a problem because first thing in executeInsert() method is locking database (I checked in source code of android 2.1, so I assume that this behavior didn't changed in 3.1).

Comment: hi,check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820556/sqlite-exception-on-resuming-android-activity).

Comment: I've done investigation. Error exists only when locale is set to Turkish and only on android 3.x. `03-14 19:54:33.360 I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(15953): sqlite returned: error code = 21, msg = API called with NULL prepared statement, db=/data/data/<package_name>/databases/database.db
03-14 19:54:33.360 I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(15953): sqlite returned: error code = 21, msg = misuse at line 58940 of [8609a15dfa], db=/data/data/<package_name>/databases/database.db`

Answer (score 0):

try using `ContentValues` to insert record.

Eg:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("column1Name", column1Value);
cv.put("column2Name", column2Value);//and so on
db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your sql statements - it might be null or zero length. I had the same issue when getting sql statements from a class which I had to break down whenever a new line character was found. The last statement contained a newline character and I tried to execute that statement after that which was empty.